# Limit access to facebook

Tags: firewall, security

I manage a network of about 60 windows computers. There is a ton of wasted time during the day because of facebook access. I want to limit employee access to facebook.com to < 30 mins per day.

I know how to block it completely using our firewall. I probably could write a proxy that all access goes through and I measure the time, but is there any easy way to limit access to facebook for my whole company to 30 mins per day?

I understand measuring 30 minutes on a stateless protocol is hard, but I'm really just asking if there is a tool that I can use that accomplished my goal of limiting access to facebook to a reassonable amount of time.

Note: I have a cisco ASA firewall

Comment: I'd suggest you re-think this policy. The staff that don't abuse the privilege of unrestricted internet access will resent those who ruined it, and the staff who did abuse it will resent you for removing that privilege. It's a recipe for some rough office politics. I would suggest, rather, that you penalise the offending staff members.

Comment: It only penalizes the people who use if for longer than 30 mins which happen to be the offenders

Comment: What kind of router do you have?

Comment: However, if you do feel that everyone is taking liberties, just block Facebook during work hours (excluding lunchtime!)

Comment: Also, how do you define usage? I leave a Facebook tab open all day at work, but I only check it once an hour or so, totally maybe 30 minutes per day. However, the ajax polling will continue, so any monitoring will say I'm on it all day.

Comment: It's a tricky thing. HTTP is stateless and there are ajax calls that would look like activity. I'm just assuming there are other admins that have been in my position and don't want to completely block facebook. Just curious of any solutions

Comment: You are trying to solve a people problem through technical means. That is not a good sign. If you are in a position within the company where you feel you can dictate what the workers can and can not do during work, simply stating this clearly should work. If it doesn't, blocking access like this will be seen as agitating, and I very much doubt you'll see any efficiency increase. It is the opposite of trust to enforce a policy like this. Even worse is some pseudo-policy of "only 30 minutes per day", where measuring "minutes" is difficult to impossible to do fairly.

Comment: I would suggest to limit the bandwidth for facebook. We did for youtube !

Comment: @DanielAndersson, We've explained it to everyone, now we're blocking it for the few that won't listen. I'm really only concerned with the technical solution to my problem, I get that some people won't like it and they're the ones who are offending.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with a proxy server (squid for example can set up time ranges on ACLs), but that's potentially a big change if you're not currently using one and don't want to set one up for just that purpose.

Me personally I'd base this stuff on performance. If someone is perceived to be wasting time on FB, make it a performance issue. Technical solutions are a way for HR to avoid the unpleasantness of actually talking to the person so they understand that they can't keep doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If only you were running squid then this could do, blocking facebook.com MTWHF and allowing user to access it between 13.00 - 14.00.

```
acl facebooktime1 time MTWHF 08:00-13:00
acl facebooktime2 time MTWHF 14:00-17:00
acl FBDomain  dstdomain .facebook.com
http_access deny FBDomain facebooktime1
http_access deny FBDomain facebooktime2
http_access allow  FBDomain
```